# Print recipe including ingredients using SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database of recipes and its associated ingredients. I have a recipes table, rec_ing table where the scales and amounts are stored and an ingredients table where all ingredients are stored. I want to display all the recipes in their entirety including their associated ingredients. So far I managed this which is display the recipes but repeating the recipe record for each ingredient.

```
  echo "COMPLETED RECIPES";
echo "<br><br>";

$sql = "SELECT r.name AS 'Recipe Name',
    r.method AS 'Method',
    ri.i_amt AS 'Amount',
    ri.i_scale AS 'Scale',
    i.i_name AS 'Ingredient'
FROM recipes r
JOIN rec_ing ri on r.r_id = ri.r_id
JOIN ingredients i on i.i_id = ri.i_id
GROUP BY r.r_id";


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Recipe Name: " . $row["Recipe Name"]. "<br>Method<br>" . $row["Method"]."<br>Ingredient". $row["Ingredient"]. " - Amount: " . $row["Amount"]. $row["Scale"]."<br><br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a GROUP BY? What do you think it does?  Also, there is no WHERE clause, so this gathers EVERY recipe in your database; is that intended?  You also have no ORDER BY, so ingredients for the same recipe won't Necessarily come out next to each other; is that intended?  Finally, when you say it's repeating the recipe record, do you mean that all the ingredients all show the recipe name and method? That's how SQL works...

Comment: I thought it will group the result by the recipe whose id is r_id. With the group by I am getting just a single ingredient and without the group by I am getting the recipe repeated with the ingredient changed. Yes I want to print all recipes.

Comment: Change it to `ORDER BY r.r_id, i.i_id`. Each row for the same recipe will still include the recipe name, but that's intended. Just write your php to only show the recipe name once, if that's what you want (check for when it's different from the previous row, then you know you're on the next recipe and need to include the name and method).

Comment: Don't add output in a comment. Edit your question and include it there. (But, as my previous comment, SQL won't include the recipe name only once, YOU have to handle that in your display code in php.  SQL is a data processing language, not a presentation layer.)

Comment: You are right! Thanks a lot! Makes sense to check the recipe name :)

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).